# Why do I get this thread error?

Tags: python, urllib2

I have this code:

```
import urllib2
import thread

a = 0
def workers():

    while 1:

        a+=1
        silva = urllib2.urlopen('http://en.dilandau.eu/download_music/said-the-whale-'+str(a)+'.html')
        si = silva.read()
        if 'var playlist' not in si:
            print a
            break

thread.start_new_thread(workers,())


while 1:
    print '---'
```

but I get an error:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function workers at 0x0000000002B1FDD8>
```

Does anyone know why I get this error?

Comment: Can you add a try/catch block to print out details on your unhandled exception? Unrelated, but I suggest moving the definition of `a` into the `workers` function definition -- it isn't shared among threads, so should be best kept local to the one thread that uses it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran a simpler version of your code and see a stack trace besides the Unhandled Exception message. It should help you to locate the problem.

There are a few improvement you should consider. First of all there is a high level library `threading` that is recommended over `thread`. Secondly you are doing a busy wait with the `while 1` loop! Use `join()` is lot more preferable. And usually it also help to put a exception handler around your worker code. For example,

```
import threading
import time
import traceback

def worker():
    try:
        for i in range(5):
            print i
            time.sleep(0.5)
        assert 0, 'bad'
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()

t = threading.Thread(target=worker)

t.start()
t.join()

print 'completed'
```

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning to "a" in the function, so it defaults to being local to the function.

The exception may be:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 0):

add `global a` in worker() function if just to eliminate error